# How can I iterate over a dataframe containing multiple conditions (using iterrows()) and flag columns based on these conditions using np.where?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, conditional-statements

I am trying to generate flags based on multiple conditions.

I would like to do the following in a more iterable way:

```
# sample dataframe
data = [[1, 1980.0, 2000.0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Item", "year1", "start_year"])
df
```

```
Item  year1   year2
1     1980.0  2000.0
```

```
# assign flag based on condition
df = df.assign(year_flag=lambda x: np.where(x["year1"] < 1985, True, False))
df
Item  year1   year2   year_flag
1     1980.0  2000.0    True
```

The way I would like to do this is the following:

```
# create a dataframe containing conditions and flags I'd like to generate
data = [
    [
        "year1",
        "(df['year1'] < 1985)",
    ],
    [
        "year2",
        "((df['year1'] < 1985) | ((df['start_year'] - df['year1']) < 10))",
    ],
]

condition_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["column", "condition"])
condition_df
```

```
column   condition
year1   (df['year1'] < 1985)
year2   ((df['year1'] < 1985) | ((df['start_year'] - df['year1']) < 10))
```

```
# iterate through rows in condition_df to generate conditions + flags
for idx, row in condition_df.iterrows():
    col = row["column"]
    condition = row["condition"]

    flag_col_name = f"{col}_flag"

    df = df.assign(flag_col_name=lambda df: np.where(condition, True, False))
```

Unfortunately this results in the following error:
[image]

I am **assuming** this is because the condition is a string and thus 1985 is also a string (could be wrong though). Is there any way I can use this method to flag a dataframe? Or an alternative method that might be more successful?

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a number is expected, and the resulting value is a string. I tried removing the quotes in the conditions themselves. No errors occur. I also added one more line to the dataframe for verification. The flags are displayed as they should. The last line gives: False.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[1, 1980.0, 2000.0], [2, 1990, 3000.0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Item", "year1", "start_year"])


data = [["year1", (df['year1'] < 1985), ],
        ["year2", ((df['year1'] < 1985) | ((df['start_year'] - df['year1']) < 10)), ], ]

condition_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["column", "condition"])


for idx, row in condition_df.iterrows():
    col = row["column"]
    condition = row["condition"]

    flag_col_name = f"{col}_flag"

    df = df.assign(flag_col_name=lambda df: np.where(condition, True, False))
    print(df)
```